# how to convert .doc .docx using tika apache?

Tags: java, apache, docx, apache-tika

i want ask to convert doc docx to file text in here code
    enter code here

```
 public DokumenExtractor(String filename) {
    context = new ParseContext();
    detector = new DefaultDetector();
    parser = new AutoDetectParser(detector);
    context.set(Parser.class, parser);
    outputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    metadata = new Metadata();

    try {
 process(filename);
 } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }

 }

  public void process(String filename) throws Exception {
      URL url;
     File file = new File(filename);
    if (file.isFile()) {
        url = file.toURI().toURL();
        this.PathFile=(file.getPath()).toString();
    } else {
        url = new URL(filename);
    }
    this.input = TikaInputStream.get(url, metadata);
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(outputstream);
    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, context); 
    input.close();
  }
```

but output like this
 PAGE   * MERGEFORMAT 36
not content of document clean ??? how to remove format Page after get string from document

Comment: what do you mean, to "file text", you mean to a .txt file?

Comment: alright,, i mean to a.txt,,, i want to get string from file doc ms.office ?

Comment: you shouldn't. not only is it possible to have formatted (instead of flat text) in a doc (or docx) file, but there can also be images and layout components in there.
if you do want to do so anyway, this might help you start:
http://poi.apache.org/text-extraction.html

Comment: i have tried,,, but when i found document's have a image,, when extraction text, it's very slow,  do you have any idea ??

Comment: images are not text. it's quite clear that 'll cause issues. never tried it myself, so can't help you out of my own experience, I'm afraid